# Ansible fails to pass parameters when executing a .run file

Tags: linux, ansible, parameter-passing

I am trying to use Ansible to install a .run file (created using Makeself 2.1.5) using the following task in a playbook:

```
- name: Install Program
  command: /home/user/folder/program.run -- /S /D=/home/user/folder/destination/
```

Here, `/S` is a switch to run a silent installation and the parameter `/D` sets the destination for the installation. Running this command in the console succeeds.

Ansible claims to run the task without error:

```
changed: [127.0.0.1] => {
    "changed": true, 
    "cmd": [
        "/home/user/folder/program.run", 
        "--", 
        "/S", 
        "/D=/home/user/folder/destination/"
    ], 
    "delta": "0:00:00.065261", 
    "end": "2017-01-06 09:08:43.114265", 
    "invocation": {
        "module_args": {
            "_raw_params": "/home/user/folder/program.run -- /S /D=/home/user/folder/destination/", 
            "_uses_shell": false, 
            "chdir": null, 
            "creates": null, 
            "executable": null, 
            "removes": null, 
            "warn": true
        }, 
        "module_name": "command"
    }, 
    "rc": 0, 
    "start": "2017-01-06 09:08:43.049004", 
    "stderr": "", 
    "stdout": "", 
    "stdout_lines": [], 
    "warnings" : []
```

So somehow the additional parameters cause the execution to fail without Ansible noticing. I've tried using the `shell` command and various ways of quoting my command, but to no avail.

If I do not pass parameters to the `.run` file, that is use `command:  /home/user/folder/program.run`, an installation prompt is opened asking for user input, which defeats the purpose of Ansible.

Does anybody have a solution for this? A possible workaround might be to use the `expect` module, but I would prefer to be able to use the command line arguments, as this is not the only file I would like to install.

I am using Ansible 2.2.0.0 on Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS.

**EDIT:**
Following techraf's advice, I found a simple solution using the `shell` module. Using `shell: konsole -e /home/user/folder/program.run /S /D=/home/user/folder/destination/` caused the installation to complete correctly. It is also possible to put the command in a script file and run it using the `script` module.

Comment: Did your "*various ways of quoting*" contain `\/S` or `\\/S` or `\\\/S`? Of course without `--` then. And the title is wrong Ansible actually succeeds in passing parameters, though `--` should prevent it.

Comment: @techraf: You almost solved my problem. When I remove the `--`, the installation routine is started correctly. I misunderstood the installer and thought that the `--` was necessary to pass arguments to the embedded script. One issue remains, as the installer opens a window and asks to "Press return" to close it. But that is an issue with the installer, not with Ansible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the `shell` module instead of `command`:

```
- name: Install Program
  shell: /home/user/folder/program.run -- /S /D=/home/user/folder/destination/
```

You are using `--` in the command execution, which actually prevents shell form parsing the arguments that follow. It's a shell built-in, not a parameter of the command.

Can't test it now (and frankly showing without the real program you run it's impossible), but I bet it should work.

---

If the above won't work, you'd probably have to put this line in a script and run it with the `script` module.

Comment: Using the `shell`module does not solve the problem. It produces the same output, except that `"_uses_shell":true`, but does not install the program.

Comment: If it won't work, you'd probably have to write a script and run it with `script`.

Comment: When I remove `--` the installer starts correctly, but opens a windows and asks to "Press return" at the end of the installation. I am going to try to write a script and see if that solves the problem.

Comment: Which is probably why you were instructed to use `--` write a script as I suggested.

Comment: I wrote a script, but then the installer still asks to "Press return", so I guess I will have to find another way. But thank you for your help, removing the `--` was an important step in the right direction.

Comment: I got the problem solved using a script by putting `konsole -e home/user/folder/program.run /S /D=/home/user/folder/destination/` in it. This way the installer doesn't open in a separate window, but in a new terminal and does not prompt for a return. Thank you again.